# Output largest difference in neighboring values

Tags: list-manipulation

I'm trying to get something that will output the values of the largest difference in a set. For instance:

```
s = {0, 5, 2, 6, 8, 3, 2, 6, 8, 4, 1, 22, 5, 7, 4, 9, 5, 3}
```

The result I would want would be `{1,22}`, because `22 - 1` is the largest difference.

```
pos = Ordering[Abs[Differences[s]], -1][[1]]
s[[pos ;; pos + 1]]
```

Seems to manage, but I feel like there should be a more direct method.

Comment: The maximum difference would be `{0, 22}`. Just use `MinMax[s]`

Comment: Well, I wanted the maximum of differences between adjacent terms.

Comment: I recommend that you edit your post to clarify your intent.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

IMO there's nothing wrong with your method, but maybe `Partition` is a bit more direct:

```
MaximalBy[Partition[s, 2, 1], Abs[Subtract @@ #] &]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
s = {0, 7, 9, -2, -3, -5, 7, -10, -10, -8};
```

Using `PositionLargest` (new in 13.2)

```
p = PositionLargest @ Abs @ Differences @ s
```

{7}

```
Extract[{p, p + 1}] @ s
```

{7, -10}

As one-liner

```
Extract[s, {#, # + 1}] & [PositionLargest @ Abs @ Differences @ s]
```

{7, -10}

Answer (score 1):

```
s = {0, 5, 2, 6, 8, 3, 2, 6, 8, 4, 1, 22, 5, 7, 4, 9, 5, 3};
```

Using `GatherBy`:

```
First@SortBy[GatherBy[Partition[s, 2, 1], #[[1]] - #[[2]] &], Last]

(*{{1, 22}}*)
```

Answer (score 0):

**Using `FindPeaks`:**

```
Clear["Global`*"];
s = {0, 5, 2, 6, 8, 3, 2, 6, 8, 4, 1, 22, 5, 7, 4, 9, 5, 3};
diffs = Join[{First@s}, s] // Differences;
vals = diffs // Det@Position[#, Max@#] & // s[[{# - 1, #}]] &
```

> {1, 22}

```
pos = diffs // FindPeaks // MaximalBy[Last] // First
```

> {12, 21}

```
peaks = diffs // FindPeaks
```

> {{2, 5}, {4, 4}, {8, 4}, {12, 21}, {16, 5}}

---

*Visualization:*

```
SequenceReplace[s, k : vals :> Sequence @@ (Style[#, Red] & /@ k)]
```

[image]

```
ListLinePlot[diffs
 , Ticks -> {Range@Length@s, Automatic}
 , AxesLabel -> {"Index", "Differences"}
 , Epilog -> {Red, AbsolutePointSize@Medium
   , Point@peaks
   , Dashed, Black
   , Line[{pos, Projection[pos, {1, 0}]}]
   , Line[{pos, Projection[pos, {0, 1}]}]
   }
 ]
```

[image]